# How to test a weatherman's predictions?

Tags: statistics

I was thinking about how one may go about statistically testing a weatherman's predictions for accuracy.  It's an interesting problem, because a weatherman will (almost) always deal in probabilities, and the probabilities they provide don't repeat very much.

There is a trivial solution to the problem, which is to wait for a decent number of repeat probabilities, see what the actual percentage is, and determine if that is within a margin of error.  However, it seems like using this method is throwing away information (namely, the non-repeating percentages). Is there a way to use that information?

Say the weatherman makes one hundred predictions about whether or not it will rain, and there are very few repeated chances in the data.  They are recorded along with whether or not it did rain on that day.  Is there a way to analyze this data to determine how accurate the weatherman is?

Comment: Each day make a virtual bet with the weatherman.  If he predicts rain with a probability of $p\neq 1$ then, if it rains,  he wins $1$ but if it doesn't then he loses $\frac p{1-p}$.  Barring algebraic error, that game should have expected value $0$.  Keep track of his wins and losses and see if $0$ is a plausible expected value.

Comment: The actual analyses of weather predictions I've seen use your trivial solution. The percentage is pretty much always (maybe actually always?) a multiple of ten, so it doesn't take long to get a reasonable number of repeats.